# #location_0.location not found in default.html

Tags: html, website

I am trying to change theme of my website, but the website builder is returning an error while uploading the theme.

## location_0.location not found in default.html

Comment: This should be raised in the StackOverflow forum which will help you with coding problems. (http://stackoverflow.com/). That being said, you'll need to provide them with more context like: Whats the content of 'default.html'? What website builder are you using? etc. etc.

Comment: Sorry i was not aware about that. By the way reference can be found at http://websitebuilderkb.com/w/Content_Locations